# chrome and chromium full screen issue

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chromium, fullscreen

I am using ubuntu and whenever I try to do fullscreen on chrome or chromium it doesn't go full screen but minimizes the window.

Interestingly this behavior doesn't happen when the window is minimized and you do fullscreen.

On firefox, everything works as expected.

[image]

**(In above image was trying to do a fullscreen to watch a video on a website)**

[image]
**(Did fullscreen while posting this question)**

As you can see in the above images, fullscreen is not happening instead it minimizes the whole window.

**version used:**

**ubuntu:** 18.04.3 LTS x86_64

**chrome:** Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**chromium:** Version 79.0.3945.79 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu, running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same issue.
I searched the whole internet for days but couldn't find any practical help. However, by trial and error, following two things worked for me:

1. Right Click on Chrome Tabs bar/ Toolbar and check `Use system title bar and borders`. 
   **Note:** When I did this, my minimize, maximize and close buttons disappeared. Hence, I used the second method.
2. If you are using Gnome Tweaks, keep `Hide Top Bar` toggle off, in the `Extensions` tab.

Comment: I found that not having the browser maximized worked as well. So I kinda figured it has something to do with this. But you really saved me here :) Thanks!